# How to start a android service from one activity and stop service in another activity?

Tags: android, service

I need to start an android service from activity and stop the activity and stop service from other activity.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidService

Answer (score 31):

A service skeleton:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "MyServiceTag";
    ...
}
```

This is part of the starting activity:

```
processStartService(MyService.TAG);

private void processStartService(final String tag) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    intent.addCategory(tag);
    startService(intent);
}
```

This is part of the stopping activity:

```
processStopService(MyService.TAG);

private void processStopService(final String tag) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    intent.addCategory(tag);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How to start/stop android service?

`startService(intent)` or `stopService(intent)`

These functions can be called from any activity.

How to stop an activity? - By this i understand that you need to navigate away from this activity. The function call

`finish()`

would remove the activity from the activity stack.

Comment: i need to continue running the service even after the activity closed and i need to close the service an another activity

Comment: I am not very sure about how to stop this service. May be you can take a static service instance to access it from any where through out the application.