# Android: stopService in another Activity

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent

How can I stop my Service in another Activity?

I start the service in my summaryActivity

```
SocketServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
SocketServiceIntent.putExtra("MessageParcelable", mp);
startService(SocketServiceIntent);
```

And start my statusActivity from my summaryActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SummaryActivity.this,
                StatusActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MessageParcelable", mp);
startActivity(intent);
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can give my Statusactivity the SocketServiceIntent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165190/how-to-call-stopservice-method-of-service-class-from-the-calling-activity-clas

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution with a service skeleton here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454381/how-to-start-a-android-service-from-one-activity-and-stop-service-in-another-act

Answer (score 9):

You should call [`Activity(ContextWrapper)#stopService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29):

```
stopService(new Intent(SummaryActivity.this, SocketService.class));
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my StatusActivity, because there is "No enclosing instance of the type SummaryActivity is accessible in scope".

Comment: So change it to `StatusActivity`. That's only an example.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work. I need the same Intent Object which I used to start the Service. I can't make a new one. I also tried to put the Intent in my Parcelable class. But also that doesn't work.

Comment: I know that I have to use the stopService method.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't explained how you're currently trying to use stopService() and what error you are getting. Expand your question a bit and you might get more helpful responses.

You need to call this from your activity:

```
stopService(new Intent(SummaryActivity.this, SocketService.class));
```

Replace "SummaryActivity" with the name of the Activity class you are stopping the service from.

Make sure you have **unbound** the service from **all** binding activities before attempting to stop it. As the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) explain, you cannot stop a Service that is currently bound to an activity.

As a design tip: It's often better to call `stopSelf()` from within the running Service rather than using `stopService()` directly. You can add a `shutdown()` method into your AIDL interface, which allows an Activity to request a `stopSelf()` be called. This encapsulates the stopping logic and gives you the opportunity to control the state of your Service when it is stopped, similar to how you would handle a `Thread`.

For example:

```
public MyService extends IntentService {

    private boolean shutdown = false;

    public void doSomeLengthyTask() {
        // This can finish, and the Service will not shutdown before 
        // getResult() is called...
        ...
    }

    public Result getResult() {
        Result result = processResult();

        // We only stop the service when we're ready
        if (shutdown) {
            stopSelf();
        }

        return result;
    }

    // This method is exposed via the AIDL interface
    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
    }

}
```

This is particularly relevant since your Intent name suggests you might be dealing with network sockets. You will want to ensure you have properly closed your socket connections before your Service is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Start the service:

```
// Java
Intent SocketServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
SocketServiceIntent.putExtra("MessageParcelable", mp);
startService(SocketServiceIntent);

//Kotlin
startService(Intent(this, SocketService::class.java))
```

Stop the service in any activity:

```
//Java
stopService(new Intent(this, SocketService.class))

//Kotlin
stopService(Intent(this, SocketService::class.java))
```

Answer (score 0):

just call stopService in summaryActivity

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `stopService()` Method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SocketService.class);
stopService(intent);
```