# stopService(intent) is not stopping service?

Tags: android, service

Here is some code for the idea of my problem:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("onDestroy------------->", "onDestroy called");
    Toast.makeText(this, " onDestroy Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //startServiceManually();
            stopService(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665256/android-stopservice-in-another-activity

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
stopService(new Intent(YOUR ACTIVITY NAME.this, YOUR SERVICE NAME.class));                                      
} catch (Exception e) {                                         e.printStackTrace();            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either this...

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, THE_SERVICE_NAME.class);
  stopService(i);
```

If that doesn't work the make sure you have an onDestroy in the service and if your using a notification the in onDestroy, put

```
 stopForeground(true);
```

Or just copy this...

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
  stopForeground(true);
}
```