# Android : stopservice from an activity that did not start it

Tags: android

I have an **App.java** that starts 2 services in `onCreate()`.

I have a **MainActivity** and in a `Log-Off` method in MainActivity, I need to **stop these 2 services**.

How do I do it? Since this MainActivity doesn't start these 2 services, is it possible to stop from it?

Comment: it is the same way as if from Activity, which started them. Use `stopService()`

Comment: *App.java that starts 2 services in onCreate()* does App class an Activity? If not than you know that even if you stop service then your custom Application class will have to live without em ?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I need to stop them from Activity and not from App.java

Comment: As I said, you can stop it in regular way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stopService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) directly like this:

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourService.class));
```

But as [seanhodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43662/seanhodges) says in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665584/4758255,

> It's often better to call stopSelf() from within the running Service
>   rather than using stopService() directly. You can add a shutdown() method into your AIDL interface, which allows an Activity to request a stopSelf() be called.

Instead using AIDL interface, you can utilize [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Something like this:

```
public MyService extends IntentService {

  private boolean shutdown = false;

  public void doSomeLengthyTask() {
    // This can finish, and the Service will not shutdown before 
    // getResult() is called...
        ...
  }

  public Result getResult() {
    Result result = processResult();

    // We only stop the service when we're ready
    if (shutdown) {
       stopSelf();
    }

    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  // This method receive the Event for stopping the service
  @Subscribe
  public void onMessageEvent(StopServiceEvent event) {
    shutdown = true;
  }
}
```

Where **StopServiceEvent** is a simple class:

```
public class StopServiceEvent {
}
```

You only need to send the event to stop the service from your **MainActivity** with:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new StopServiceEvent());
```