# Stop a service that was started from another service, in another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a Sticky Service B, that is started from the Service A. The service A finishes itself soon after starting service B. I want to stop the Service B from the Activity C. How can I do this?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454381/how-to-start-a-android-service-from-one-activity-and-stop-service-in-another-act) link gives a way to stop a service from another activity but in this case the service was started by an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a BroadcastReceiver to get an event across to the service and have it terminate itself.

Comment: You can broadcast an event from wherever you want and catch it wherever you want. I was suggesting to create a broadcast receiver in your service. Or use any other Event Bus system for that matter.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggest but the service does not stop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `stopService` from your Activity. It does not matter whether the Service was started by an Activity or another Service as long as you provide a valid context in your intent. If the Service is not bound to any of the clients, then calling `stopService` will stop the Service.

```
stopService(new Intent(ActivityC.this, ServiceB.class));
```

If you want the Service to stop itself, call `stopSelf()` inside the Service.

Answer (score 0):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

1.create function handleStart()

```
private void handleStart(){
    //write your code here
}
```

2.override onStartCommand

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(startId == Service.START_STICKY) {
        handleStart();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }else
        return  Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

3.call stopService

```
stopService(new Intent(ActivityC.this, ServiceB.class));
```